# Getting a short wifi password to work on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, password, wifi

Wifi password became a problem to me. My wifi password consists of only 4 letters but my Linux Mint 12 is expecting more than 7 letters - until then connect button is disabled.

Can I work around this issue?

Comment: What kind of encription do you have? I think WEP uses 10 or 26 characters, and WPA uses 8-63 characters, making Mints behaviour justified, no?

Comment: Change the password to a longer one. The length limitation is there for **your** security.

Comment: @Psirus security is one thing, having ability to connect to the internet on hotspot that you are not in control where password is short and windows connects normally is another. Why everyone are so arrogant here and just won't provide solution to this apart from claiming - change password. What if you can't or don't know how? 

Having standards that *every* router allow to break them is not really a standard is it? It's more of a suggestion that way.

Comment: @JackLeo I wasn't being arrogant. The two most common wireless security protocols are WEP and WPA(2). Both use at least 8 characters for a passphrase, i.e. you can't have a passphrase with less. Therefore he might be using some more exotic protocol I haven't heard of (totally possible) and Mint doesn't support it either. But thats why I was ASKING him what encription is being used. You interpreted quite a lot into my comment.